# Direct downconversion (IQ downconverter) with ASK modulation-- what kind of Balun do you need?

Tags: modulation, radio

I have a simple but confused question.

I am trying demodulate a 915MHz ASK modulated signal with direct downconversion. So what I am building up is:
Antenna --> SAW bandpass filter @915MHz --> LNA --> Direct IQ down-converter (max2021 [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX2021.pdf) LO = 915MHZ) --> balun? --> decoder(sdr)

The max2021 downconverter is a 4-ports output: I+,I-,Q+,Q-. To put the differential signal back to single-ended, I was taught this is a balun's job.

But when I trying to build this system the balun concept is confusing. If successfully down-converted and DC blocked  , the IQ outputs are just unmodulated differential square pulses-- so what kind of balun do I use and at what frequency? Do I use a digital buffer in this case instead of an analog balun?

ps: I am using direct downconversion for carrier interference cancellation(move the carrier interference to DC then DC block) and design simplicity; and IQ downconverter to avoid phase ambiguity.

Comment: Interesting system, but in all honesty, the balun's physical properties are probably more of a concern of electronics.stackexchange.com. But: if you've downconverted to IQ baseband, you don't attach a full SDR, but only a pair of ADCs, which quite commonly have differential inputs. If you buy an SDR, that typically includes all downconverters necessary; maybe you'd want to clarify what you mean with "SDR".

Comment: by the way, you're assuming perfect frequency sync between receiver and transmitter. You'll find that to not work out (usually not at all), so you'd generally want to do the carrier suppression in software, or have a frequency control loop, or do some low-IF trick.

Comment: In addition to the carrier offset that Marcus said; if this is a digital receiver, as soon as you sample the DC blocked signal the ADC will inevitably have an offset such that you need to cancel that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your intentions clearer about "using direct downconversion for carrier interference cancellation" to "move the carrier interference to DC then DC block" in your scheme of "[d]irect downconversion ... with ASK modulation", had you attached the circuit drawing.

But, for a prescribed application of MAX2021 as GSM/CDMA signaling demodulator, you need a **[power combiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_dividers_and_directional_couplers)** -- in fact, three power combiners: two for differential components in the $I$ and $Q$ paths and one to combine the single-ended $I,Q$ signals into one baseband signal. The "power" determinant should not confuse you: the name is inherited from a nomenclature of microwave power devices (e.g., microwave power amplifiers, attenuators, etc.), but, when used in the context of modulators/demodulators, designates exactly the component you need to combine $I_{+}/Q_{+}, I_{-}/Q_{-}$ outputs into single-ended signals. Besides, [microwaves101.com](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/power-combining) directly indicates a correspondence between baluns and power combiners in the section **180 degree combiners**.

Also, the baseband output of MAX2021 is not "square pulses" with zero rise/fall times; after output filtering according to a circuit shown in *Figure 4. Baseband Port Typical Filtering and DC Return Network*, baseband outputs look more like an "analog" signal with a frequency range defined by the symbol data rate.

In *Figure 5. Demodulator Combining Diagram* (page 15), the MAX2021 datasheet of your reference directs you to use Mini-Circuits' 180° power combiner [ZFSCJ-2-1](https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/ZFSCJ-2-1.pdf) and 0° power combiner [ZFSC-2-1W-S+](https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=ZFSC-2-1W-S%2B). ZFSCJ-2-1 features wideband operations, 1MHz to 3GHz. If your symbol data rate requires frequency below 1MHz, there are available on the market lumped-element/resistive power dividers/combiners of other suppliers, with a lower frequency value down to 4KHz and even DC.

Read also the [MiniCircuits blog article](https://blog.minicircuits.com/understanding-power-splitter-combiner-power-handling-with-coherent-and-non-coherent-signals) and the application note [AN10-006](https://www.minicircuits.com/appdoc/AN10-006.html).